# Instead of appending all alert messages together show only latest one and remove all the previous alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

[image]

I want to remove all the old alerts and show only the latest one.

The code snippet that is adding these alerts:

```
$("#update-timeline-audit").parent().after('<div class="alert alert-success inline"> <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>No new tweets since the last audit</div>');
```

Please suggest me a way to solve this repitition of alerts issue! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.html()` instead of `.after()`

`.after()` appends the HTML each time while `.html()` resets the HTML each time.

Comment: $("#update-timeline-audit").html() 
This? Needn't write parent then, right?

Comment: .html() targets the exact element. So just target the div where you are storing your errors and use .html() on that. I can't see your HTML so I can't say for sure but just make sure you run .html() on the div you want to store your error messages.

Comment: Some problem. #update-timeline-audit is the button "Refresh" I want to show the error message after that just like these are being shown now, just that it should be just one! .html seems to work but it makes changes in the button itself.. any way to add error message after the button